# Expanding current column does not work as expected with a width cookie

Tags: org-mode, org-table

From [the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html#Column-width-and-alignment):

> C-c TAB (org-table-toggle-column-width)
>
> ```
> Shrink or expand current column.
>
> If a width cookie specifies a width W for the column, shrinking it 
> displays the first W visible characters only. Otherwise, the column is
> shrunk to a single character.
>
> When called before the first column or after the last one, ask for a list of column ranges to operate on.
> ```

Example:

```
| foo                                     | bar         |
|-----------------------------------------+-------------|
| <10> |
| foooooooooooo                           | barrrrr     |
| fooo                                    | barrrrrrrrr |
| foooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo | barrr       |
```

If I do `C-c TAB`, it does not shrink and I get the message "Before first heading" in the echo area. But if I do `TAB`, the first column shrinks. If I do `TAB` again, the cursor moves the next cell. If I do `C-c TAB`, it does not expand and I get the message "Before first heading" in the echo area.

Bottom line: I can shrink, not expand.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce what you describe with org-mode 9.1.9. <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> works like it is expected with org-mode 9.2.3.

In org-mode 9.1.19 <kbd>C.c</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> runs `outline-show-children` while in 9.2.3 it runs  `org-ctrl-c-tab` with the following description:

> Toggle columns width in a table, or show children.
>   Call `org-table-toggle-column-width` if point is in a table.
>   Otherwise, call `org-show-children`.

So, if you really want to get `org-table-toggle-column-width` working update to the [org-version of org-mode](https://orgmode.org/elpa.html) or to the version at the [gnu elpa package archive](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org.html).

[Org mode 9.2](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.2/lisp/org.el#L19042) was the first official version where `org-ctrl-c-tab` was bound to <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>.